# angular-ui-router reload view but not refresh page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

```
 $state.go('home.tooltabs',{toolMenuView:toolMenu},{
       reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true
  });
```

when `$state.current` is not **home.tooltabs**, view render is correct,But when  `$state.current` is **home.tooltabs** and options not add `reload: true` ,the view will not be rendered, add `reload:true` option ,the full page will refresh. How can I only reload view instead of refresh full page.

**router config:**

```
mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/dashboard");
    $stateProvider.state("home",{
       url:"/home",
        views:{
            'header':{
                templateUrl:"/main/header"
            },
            'menu':{
                templateUrl:"/main/menu",
                controller:'menuCtrl'
            },
            'content':{
                templateUrl:"/main/content",
                controller:function($scope,$stateParams){

                }
            }
        }
    })
        .state('home.profile',{
            url:'/profile',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl: '/profile/index'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.dashboard',{
            url:'/dashboard',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl: '/dashboard/index'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.tooltabs',{
            url:'/tools/tooltabs',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl: '/tools/tooltabs',
                    controller:'toolTabsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.toolsindex',{
            url:'/tools/index',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl: '/tools/index',
                    controller:'toolIndexCtrl'
                }
            }
        })  .state('home.openapi',{
            url:'/tools/index',
            views:{
                'content@':{
                    templateUrl: '/tools/index'
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: could you please post your route configuration as well?

Comment: @ ex0dm3nt , add route config